# How does a Microcontroller Start and What would be the state of GPIO pins during Initialization

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, digital-logic, gpio

I am using [S32K142](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/S32K-DS.pdf) Microcontroller 64-pin.

I am finding some difficulty in reading the reference manual of the controller. I want to know how does the microcontroller initially starts and are there only two basic power modes in the microcontroller?

For power modes, I read in page 1141 of the reference manual. I can see only RUN and STOP (Sleep) as the basic power modes, however there are VLPR and VLPS and other modes. But the basic modes I could find was RUN and SLEEP.

The power mode transition state diagram is given on page 1147.

My question :

1. How does the microcontroller start?
   I am asking in the sense like, what would be the state of GPIO pins during the initial start ? Like, once we provide input voltage to the MCU, there would be some delay till the microcontroller starts its normal operation right? In this delay time, what would be the state be? I read that, the pins would be in High-Z during this short time. But I could not find this High-Z information in the reference manual. Have I missed it?

My main objective is to mention the state of the pin in the working modes of the microcontroller. From what I have read, the modes are -

1. DURING RESET
2. NORMAL RUN
3. STOP (SLEEP MODE)

Just stating the below for an example so that with an example, I can understand better,

Suppose, I have an IC and an I2C device connected to this microcontroller. This Microcontroller provides the Enable to the IC and also establishes I2C Communication with the other I2C Device during normal operation. So, can someone tell me how should I give the information for the pins during the above 3 mentioned states?

Comment: The information you need, as well as a lot more, is in the __S32K1xx Series Reference Manual__. The copy on the NXP website seems to require a username and password but here is an external copy I found (I cannot attest to the accuracy): https://usermanual.wiki/Document/S32KReferenceManual.1978847578/view

Comment: Yes thank you. I have check the reference manual. I am unable to find what I am looking for

Comment: The default values of all pins depends on their corresponding registers, which in turn is documented per register. It is common that all pins are set as inputs out of reset to save a bit of current.

Comment: @Lundin, could you tell me where did you find that the pins would be inputs out of reset from the reference manual?

Comment: @Newbie In the data direction register of the relevant port.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @Lundin